# Oracle.DataAccess.dll getting copied to Release folder despite Copy Local = false

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, release-mode, debug-mode

I have a .NET solution which contains multiple projects. All the projects which refer the Oracle.DataAccess.dll have set Copy Local = false for it. When I build the solution in `Debug` mode, the dll does not get copied to `bin\Debug` folder but in `Release` mode, it does get copied to `bin\Release` folder.

I am maintaining 64-bit and 32-bit dlls in bin64 and bin32 folder and resolving at runtime for these and it is working fine in Debug mode. But in `Release` mode when application runs, I am getting exception that says Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess.dll', .....

Why is the dll getting copied to `bin\Release` folder ?

After changing the [Verbosity of MSBuild in Output Window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/10/07/did-you-know-you-can-configure-the-msbuild-verbosity-in-the-output-window-329.aspx), I found:

Copying file from "C:\app\brij\product\11.1.0\client_1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" to "bin\Release\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"

Comment: Actually, the ending of this would be even more interesting: `"Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess.dll...."`  <-- what is here?

Comment: @T.S. that exception is at runtime due to 32-bit/64-bit mismatch. If build process `in RELEASE mode` won't copy the Oracle.DataAccess.dll in bin\Release folder then the correct dll would be used from bin32 and bin64 folders.

Comment: You can create post build event, where you detect configuration and copy appropriate DLL into the output folder